# How can I get the edges that connect two specific vertices in Orient db

Tags: orientdb

I have experimented with the documentation and the console but didn't find a way to do this.

Vertex with property "A",Vertex with property "B" and Edge with label "Connected".

I want to find out the edges that connect these two vertices and get the *id's of the edges*.

I haven't been able to do that getting the edges. I can do

```
select from (SELECT EXPAND(BOTH('Connected')) FROM Tag WHERE prop='A') where prop='B'
```

but I need to get the edge @rid. if I change BOTH to BOTHE then how can I specifically ask for the tag with prop B.

I have also tried doing :

```
SELECT FROM Connected WHERE IN=(SELECT FROM TAG WHERE prop = 'A') AND OUT = (SELECT FROM TAG WHERE prop = 'B')
```

but I don't get anything from that

**Update:**

```
select from Connected where (out in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagA') AND in in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagB')) OR (out in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagB') AND in in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagA'))
```

this solves the issue but isn't there a more straightforward way? I think this scans all the edges with the given label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1:

```
SELECT FROM (
    SELECT EXPAND(BOTHE('Connected')) FROM Tag WHERE prop='A'
) WHERE in.prop='B' or out.prop='B'
```

2:

```
SELECT FROM Connected 
WHERE (in.prop = 'A' AND out.prop = 'B') OR (in.prop = 'B' AND out.prop = 'A')
```

2b:

```
SELECT FROM Connected 
LET $inProp = in.prop, $outProp = outProp = out.prop 
WHERE ($inProp = 'A' AND $outProp = 'B') OR ($inProp = 'B' AND $outProp = 'A')
```

I'm not sure which is fastest thou, you have to try it out since it depends on your db and other parts of the query. 2b is faster than 2, but only by a super small margin.

Comment: that's a correct answer but I really think we are scanning all the Connected nodes instead of starting from graph node A. I don't know how no.1 scans. I also have zero db entries right now so can't judge.

Comment: Yeah, we are. 
No. 1 scans all the Tag nodes which isn't necessarily better. The best way (if you don't have access to an id) is to use an index on Tag.prop. This way the inner select can be done very quickly and it will definitely be the fastest solution.

Comment: Given that I do have an index on the prop, your proposal is to use no.1 then?

Comment: Absolutely, just make sure the inner select use index and it will definitely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select from Connected where out in (select from Tag WHERE prop = 'B' ) and in in (select from Tag WHERE prop = 'A' )
```

Comment: select from Connected where (out in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagA') AND in in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagB')) OR (out in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagB') AND in in (select from Tag where tagName='testTagA'))

this does the trick yes. Seems like an overkill so I think there must be a better way? otherwise I will accept your answer

Comment: SELECT FROM Connected WHERE IN=(SELECT FROM TAG WHERE prop = 'A') AND OUT = (SELECT FROM TAG WHERE prop = 'B') does not return results because (SELECT FROM TAB WHERE prop = 'A) can return more than one vertex.
You can use also this query select outE("Connected")[in.prop="A"] from Tag where prop = "B"